# JavaScript dynamically expand/contract matrix - how to implement this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to create a Matrix in JavaScript to hold some data. It should be able to dynamically expand and contract when I decide to append a new matrix, without losing data (except if rows that contain data are removed, then that data is lost).

Lets say I have a 4x3 matrix.

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

Then I want to add a 6x5 matrix. Now it looks like this...

```
[][][][] [][][][][][]
[][][][] [][][][][][]
[][][][] [][][][][][]
         [][][][][][]
         [][][][][][]
```

However, I want to fill those empty spaces as well, without resetting the original data cells. Like this:

```
[][][][] [][][][][][]
[][][][] [][][][][][]
[][][][] [][][][][][]
[][][][] [][][][][][]
[][][][] [][][][][][]
```

So far I've started with: `this.mainMatrix = Array(x).fill(Array(y));`

Now how do I proceed?

Comment: You must beware of the fact that arrays are reference types and you may easily end up an array of arrays all referring to a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a matrix (dense & sparse) library like [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html)?

```js
var matrixA = math.matrix([
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
]); // Matrix
var matrixB = math.matrix([
  [5, 6],
  [7, 8]
]); // Matrix

var matrixC = math.add(matrixA, matrixB);

console.log(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC)
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.2.1/math.min.js"></script>
```